# error with double word subtraction in 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086, bigint

i want to subtract 16bit numbers in emu 8086
my other values are getting calculated properly but when the loop reaches the to subtract 0eeee-0ffff it is showing the value of eeef and carry flag is set to 1 but the value should be -1111,

```
; multi-segment executable file template.
    
    data segment
       a1 dw 1199h,2255h,0FFFFh
       a2 dw 2210h,3333h,0EEEEh
       count dw 0003h
    ends
    
    code segment                 
    start:
           mov ax,data
           mov ds,ax
           
           lea si,a1
           lea di,a2
           mov cx,count
           
    next:
           mov bx,[si]
           mov ax,[di]
           sub ax,bx
           sbb ax,0000h 
          ; das
           mov [di],ax
           inc si
           inc si
           inc di
           inc di
           loop next
                    
           mov ah,4ch
           int 21h
    
    end start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.
```

Comment: 0xEEEF is -0x1111

Comment: You're applying the borrow output to the current word, not the next iteration.  There should be only one `sbb` in your loop, no `sub`.  (Clear CF before entering the loop, or peel the first iteration so you can start with `sub`.)  Or if this is supposed to be 3 *separate* word-sized subtractions, don't use SBB, and don't call it "double-word" subtraction.  A dword is 32 bits.  (But you have 48 bits in each of your bigint values a1 and a2.)

Comment: Note that subtracting `0xFFFF` (signed `-1`) is the same binary operation as adding `1`, except for the CF output.

Comment: Is this supposed to be one 3-word bigint, or 3 separate subtracts of 3 pairs of words?  I'm now leaning towards the latter, but found the title misleading when retagging.  Please remove the [bigint] tag if that's not what you're doing, and don't call it "double word" subtract in the title.  "Double word" has a specific technical meaning in x86, dword being 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You're right in that 0EEEEh - 0FFFFh is equal to -1111h. The thing is that **emu8086 is not showing the result with a prepended minus sign**.

The way to remove the minus sign, so to negate the value (`neg`), is to first toggle all of the bits in the number (`not`) and then add 1 (`inc`).

```
     -0001000100010001b   -1111h

not   1110111011101110b    EEEEh
inc   1110111011101111b    EEEFh
```

Following `sub ax, bx`, emu8086 will have shown EEEFh.
The `sbb ax, 0000h` that follows should be removed from the text.

Comment: x86 has a `neg` instruction which gives the same result as `not`+`inc`, but more efficiently.  (It sets FLAGS according to `0 - x`, though, which has the same integer result by definition of 2's complement.)  If you want to show negation by `~x + 1`, that's fine, just don't say it's *the* way, because it's a silly inefficient way to actually do it in practice.

Comment: @PeterCordes The user is not encouraged to do this in code. Of course they would have to use `neg`. What I show is what we actually do in our heads when we negate a 2's complement number. The OP was looking at emu8086's debug output, so everything was playing in their head...

Comment: Right, like I said, I'm nit-picking the text, not the choice of what to show in the code block.  Good edit.